# What is this "hand with three sparkles" button on the sidebar of Motorola, and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: android-12, motorola, overlay

I have a Motorola phone running on Android 12. I have no idea what this button is with the hand with three sparkles above it is and I want to get rid of it.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [OP's own founding](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/249171/what-is-this-hand-with-three-sparkles-button-on-the-sidebar-of-motorola-and-h#comment335267_249171) on [Reddit - Android 12 Moto Gestures floating button problem.](https://www.reddit.com/r/motorola/comments/thnbxm/android_12_moto_gestures_floating_button_problem/), **this is a "Swipe to split" shortcut accessibility button on Motorola devices**,

---

[DaveOJ12's reply](https://www.reddit.com/r/motorola/comments/thnbxm/comment/i197l3h/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3),

> Try this:
>
> https://reddit.com/comments/tdadwe
>
> Settings
>
> Accessibility
>
> Swipe to split

[phKoon (OP)'s reply](https://www.reddit.com/r/motorola/comments/thnbxm/comment/i19ku62/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

> Moments after I had posted, I managed to get rid of ir by shutting down the "Moto Actions and Gestures" (that is nowhere to be found except via the expanded windows view), by opening any of the actions menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C4Q1.jpg
>
> But that hint of yours would've been so much simpler, it's spot on.

[Outside_Active_7574's reply](https://www.reddit.com/r/motorola/comments/thnbxm/comment/iooi0zj/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

> Thank you so much; this worked a treat, though I found leaving on "Use Swipe to split" and turning off "Swipe to split shortcut", is what allowed to me to keep Moto Actions but removed the floating logo.
> Cheers.